# Setting alpha of background also effects text within children

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app, but when I change the alpha value of the background, its children are also effected and every text within the element is faded out.

How can I remove the fade from the text in the layout?

**Here is my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/whitesmoke"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp">
        <ImageView
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/iv_user_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                app:civ_border_width="5dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/civ_user_profile"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp" />
           <LinearLayout
               android:alpha="0.5"
               android:background="@color/colorAccent"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <TextView
                   android:textSize="18dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                   android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
               <LinearLayout
                   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                   android:paddingRight="5dp"
                   android:paddingTop="3dp"
                   android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                   android:alpha="30"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/iv_user_like"
                       android:layout_width="15dp"
                       android:layout_height="15dp" />
                   <TextView
                       android:textSize="10dp"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                       android:id="@+id/tv_user_like_count"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
               </LinearLayout>
           </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tl_user_nav_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@color/whitesmoke"
        android:id="@+id/user_main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**And here is a screenshot of the result:**

[image: text within children is faded]

Comment: If you set the alpha to a view it will only affect that view, if you set it to a viewgroup it will affect all its childs

Comment: So how can I solve my problem please ?

Comment: Im not sure to what view are you applying the alpha and what is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your background is just a color you can remove the alpha from your layout.
Instead of using @color/colorAccent you can use a hex color like #BBFF80AB
Hex colors are have a structure like: #AARRGGBB where AA-alpha, RR-red, GG-green, BB-blue. By changing the alpha of that color, you change the alpha of only the background, and not all of the views'. So, in your case, make the layout be like this:

> `<LinearLayout
>                  android:background="#80FF80AB"
>                  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
>                  android:layout_weight="1"
>                  android:orientation="vertical"
>                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">`